# add-Migration Error No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

i am trying to add migration to a DbContext  ,

```
add-migration initial -verbose
```

I get Error

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
>   provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring
>   method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.
>   If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
>   accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and
>   passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

i have two .netcore class library project and and ,netcore unit test project  in my solution

1. Domain(Poco Classess)
2. Repository (.Net Core 2.1 , EntitiFrameworkCore 2.1.4)
3. RepositoryTest

here is my DataContext Class

```
 public class DataContext:DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> option) : base(option)
        {

        }

        public DataContext()
        {

        }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Cart { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CatalogItem> CatalogItem { get; set; }
 }
```

a constructor with DbContextOptions object is already there .

what could be possibly the problem ?

and here is a class in test project.

```
 public class CustomerRepositoryIntegrationTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void should_add_customer()
        {
            //Arrange
            var option = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=ecommerce;Integrated Security=SSPI").Options;

            //Act
            using (DataContext dataConext = new DataContext(option))
            {

                dataConext.Database.Migrate();
                customer actual = new Customer()
                dataConext.Customer.Add(actual);
                dataConext.SaveChanges();

                var expected = dataConext.Customer.FirstOrDefault();

                //Assert
                expected.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
            }


            //Assert
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you don't seem to have configured the DbContext just as the error message tells you. Where's your context configuration?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it is in my test project . i just update the code

Comment: and what the hell is wrong with question ? why do you have negative vote?

Comment: The `add-migration` command has no idea about your unit test, so for that command you have not configured the context. The easiest way to solve this is to override `OnConfiguring` and configure the context if that hasn't happened (as it happens on your test)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto should i do it in my test project ?

Comment: No, that's done on the DataContext class

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto , do you think it is right place to do ? because my production and test database is different .

Comment: You don't have an ASP.NET Core project or a command line project to act as startup projects so that's your only choice

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto , can i set my test project as startup project ?

Comment: No, a test project is not an application project

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto , it is very stupid that microsoft has not mention such thing in its documentation  just same as always leaving developer with frustration .

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto , i finally figure it out how i can do it without startup project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a class that implement [IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.idesigntimedbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-5.0) in test project and set test project as  startup project

```
public class TemporaryDataContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DataContext>
{
    public DataContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var option = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
        .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=IbReport;Integrated Security=SSPI").Options;
        return new DataContext(option);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! So much better than using a throwaway console app. In .net core I ran `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate  --startup-project <myTestProject>` from my context project directory and things worked beautifully. Thank you so much.